# How can I make this function synchronous with Asyn/await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await

I'm trying to make this code to be synchronous but for some reason async/await doesn't work.. Im working in React-native with two differents modules. I want to see my geolocation in googleMaps but it gets me a error because the asynchronous stuff.

App is the root component, im importing getLocalitation function.

```
export default class App extends Component {
    Appmetod = async () => {
        const resp = await getLocalitation();
        console.log('Appmetod: latitud: ' + resp.latitude);
        Linking.openURL(`http://www.google.com/maps/place/-33.317597,-71.405500`);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <Button title="Click me" onPress={this.Appmetod } />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

```
const getLocalitation = () =>{
    console.log('DENTRO DE GetLocalitaion');

    const geoOptions={
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeOut: 10000
    };

    const coordenates =  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( geoSucces,goFailure, geoOptions);
    console.log('DESPUES DE COORDENATES');

    return coordenates;
} 

const geoSucces = (position) => {
    console.log('DENTRO DE GEOSUCCEES');

    const latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    const longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    const coordenates={
        latitude: latitude,
        longitude: longitude
    };

    console.log('COORDENATES: ' + coordenates.latitude);
    return coordenates;
}

const goFailure = (err) => {
    console.log('Error en al geolocalizar: ' + err);
    return null;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
C:\Users\jnunez\React-Native\Proyects\geolocation\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\infoLog.js:16 Running application "geolocation" with appParams: {"rootTag":161}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
C:\Users\jnunez\React-Native\Proyects\geolocation\src\getLocalitation.js:2 DENTRO DE GetLocalitaion
C:\Users\jnunez\React-Native\Proyects\geolocation\src\getLocalitation.js:10 DESPUES DE COORDENATES
C:\Users\jnunez\React-Native\Proyects\geolocation\src\getLocalitation.js:16 DENTRO DE GEOSUCCEES
C:\Users\jnunez\React-Native\Proyects\geolocation\src\getLocalitation.js:26 COORDENATES: -32.92098393
C:\Users\jnunez\React-Native\Proyects\geolocation\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:67 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'latitude' of undefined
    at _callee$ (blob:http://localhost:8081/19d9ce97-42d2-4939-91b8-160b264c9c79:1895:58)
    at tryCatch (blob:http://localhost:8081/19d9ce97-42d2-4939-91b8-160b264c9c79:41538:19)
    at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (blob:http://localhost:8081/19d9ce97-42d2-4939-91b8-160b264c9c79:41713:24)
    at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (blob:http://localhost:8081/19d9ce97-42d2-4939-91b8-160b264c9c79:41581:23)
    at tryCatch (blob:http://localhost:8081/19d9ce97-42d2-4939-91b8-160b264c9c79:41538:19)
    at invoke (blob:http://localhost:8081/19d9ce97-42d2-4939-91b8-160b264c9c79:41614:22)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/19d9ce97-42d2-4939-91b8-160b264c9c79:41624:15
    at tryCallOne (blob:http://localhost:8081/19d9ce97-42d2-4939-91b8-160b264c9c79:45254:14)
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/19d9ce97-42d2-4939-91b8-160b264c9c79:45355:17
    at blob:http://localhost:8081/19d9ce97-42d2-4939-91b8-160b264c9c79:46233:21
console.warn @ C:\Users\jnunez\React-Native\Proyects\geolocation\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\YellowBox\YellowBox.js:67
onUnhandled @ C:\Users\jnunez\React-Native\Proyects\geolocation\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Promise.js:45
onUnhandled @ C:\Users\jnunez\React-Native\Proyects\geolocation\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\rejection-tracking.js:71
(anonymous) @ C:\Users\jnunez\React-Native\Proyects\geolocation\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:256
_callTimer @ C:\Users\jnunez\React-Native\Proyects\geolocation\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:152
callTimers @ C:\Users\jnunez\React-Native\Proyects\geolocation\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:414
__callFunction @ C:\Users\jnunez\React-Native\Proyects\geolocation\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:366
(anonymous) @ C:\Users\jnunez\React-Native\Proyects\geolocation\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:106
__guard @ C:\Users\jnunez\React-Native\Proyects\geolocation\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:314
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue @ C:\Users\jnunez\React-Native\Proyects\geolocation\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:105
(anonymous) @ debuggerWorker.js:80
```

Comment: Solved:     `return new Promise ((resolve, rejection) => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( (position) =>resolve(position.coords),rejection, geoOptions);
    });` is the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` / `async` do not stop code being asynchronous.

They are tools which let you write non-asynchronous **style** code by managing promises.

You can only `await` a promise. `getLocalitation` does not return a promise.

See [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises) to get a promise for `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`.

Comment: How would you do it in this case? Restructuring the code and executing http://www.google.com/maps/place/${resp.latitude},${resp.longitude} inside geoSucces ?? are there any other options?

Comment: @Braven — I'd wrap `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` in a promise and return that promise.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work [link](https://gist.github.com/BravenxX/d7d79c09537847109e1a76565504f9a1)  I dont understand

Answer (score 0):

It is because you're using **await** keyword with a function that is not **async**

`const resp = await getLocalitation();`

You can either put an **async** before the `()` when defining **getLocation** or you can just remove **await** from `const resp = await getLocalitation()`, since you don't need to use **await** with something that does not return a promise.

In case you want to make `getLocalitation` async you do it like this

```
const getLocalitation = async () =>{
    console.log('DENTRO DE GetLocalitaion');

    const geoOptions={
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeOut: 10000
    };

    const coordenates =  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition( geoSucces,goFailure, geoOptions);
    console.log('DESPUES DE COORDENATES');

    return coordenates;
}
```

Comment: That won't work. `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` **is** async (but it doesn't return a promise).

Comment: you're right, it only fixes the async/await error. I'd go on a different approach by passing a method reference.

Comment: If I want the AppMetod to make this: Linking.openURL(`http://www.google.com/maps/place/${resp.latitude},${resp.longitude}`) will doesn't work: resp.latitude=undefined... How can i fix this?

Comment: You'll need to do something this like this https://jsfiddle.net/mszfkjpo/

Comment: thx it worked! But how can I do it without linking.operURL inside the callback of navigator? I mean, like a sync code like my example,,

Comment: Not with `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`, since it works with callbacks