# Make setState() to change state variables for whole class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the code as below which changes the values of cords inside the state if the device location is available.

```
class App extends Component{
  state={
    cords:{
      longitude:24.01,
      latitude:38.22
    },
    data:{}
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Mounted")
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position=>{
      let newCords={
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude
      }
      this.setState({cords:newCords});
      console.log("Inside",this.state);//displays new values
    });
    };
    console.log(this.state);// displays old values
```

The change in state() can be observed only inside the arrow function. How to get the changed values outside the whole if-block?

Comment: this answer might help you 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30783011/8240417

Comment: It immediately called the console. Try to add `setTimeout`. Instead, you should use the callback function of `setState`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since setState is async, so, you will get the updated values inside callback function of state only i.e. arrow function of state in this case. Since `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` is an async function, that even does not returns Promise. So, once you execute this, the code further moves on to execute further lines of code, but by this time the response of `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` has not come, and since this time the state and cords are also not set. So, you will never be getting the coords value outside that if statement, until your API call `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` succeeds. Once that gets success, than the code that you have written inside its call back i.e. written below executes.

```
let newCords={
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude
      }
      this.setState({cords:newCords});
      console.log("Inside",this.state);//displays new values
```

So, this is how your code is working. Probably, you need to change your logic. Since `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`  is also not returning promise so, you can't await also. Although, its not recommended, but you can setTimeOut for sometime blindly, by the time response comes like below

```
 componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Mounted")
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position=>{
      let newCords={
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude
      }
      this.setState({cords:newCords});
      console.log("Inside",this.state);//displays new values
    });
    };
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.state);
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: It is the same thing, it will now say 'newCords' not defined. @raghvender-kataria

Comment: Please decalre it the same way, i.e. outside if statement, as I have done in 3rd line. If the value is assigned to it inside if, then for sure you will get the values of it outside if, since you have decalred the variable outside if

Comment: I had tried this, in this case it says 'cords' is undefined.

Comment: I have given the reasoning that how its actually working. Please go through the updated answer

Comment: This method works. But it would be more effective if the function navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition can be made synchronous.

Comment: I believe you can check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56636911/10720296

Answer (score 0):

I think @Anarno's answer is correct. I don't know why is it downvoted. The function from navigator is async and before it mutates the state, you are trying to log the state outside the if, it will give you the old value for sure and I am not able to relate what is the logging for, you will get the state value updated. Use React-tools instead of console loggers to see how your state changes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use temp variables to get the values outside the if block it can be used in following way

```
componentDidMount() {
let temp={}
console.log("Mounted")
if (navigator.geolocation) {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position=>{
  let newCords={
    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
    longitude: position.coords.longitude
  }
temp=newCords;
  this.setState({cords:newCords});
  console.log("Inside",this.state);//displays new values
});
};
console.log(this.state);
console.log('temp variable having new data',temp)
}
```

Comment: This is same as using 'let newCords' to declare it before if-block. It says 'temp' as undefined.